# How to prepare for upgrade to Jelly Bean - Droid Bionic

Tags: updates, 4.1-jelly-bean, motorola-droid-bionic

Motorola and Verizon [have announced](http://news.verizonwireless.com/news/2012/10/droid-bionic-android-ice-cream-sandwich.html) that the Bionic will be upgraded to Jelly Bean starting April 15.   Aside from backing up any data that isn't synced with a cloud service, are there any steps that should be taken in preparation?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Carbon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=de) to backup your applications data. If your devices is rooted you can make a complete [nandroid backup](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1818321) using CWM.

Comment: +1 For some reason, Carbon is showing not available for the Bionic, even though its minimum OS level is 4.0 (the Bionic currently has 4.0.4).   I will definitely be installing it on my other device that it is compatible with.

Comment: Koush (the developer for Carbon) stated that Motorola phones break the backup technique - so he is barring them from being able to use it (source: https://plus.google.com/u/0/103583939320326217147/posts/Mz4YyHRgkoj)

Comment: @DylanYaga - that's too bad.   I was hoping I'd be able to use it after the JB upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have rooted your phone, these are the steps that I have had to do in the past to get the OTA to work:

Applications

- BionicBootstrap.apk is custom bootloader used to Save/Restore entire ROM's (backup of my phone)
- OTA RootKeeper roots and unroots the phone.

For OTA:

1. Unfreeze all apps (Stay in Root)
2. Needed to uninstall Bionic Bootstrap
3. Reboot
4. Open ES File Manager and remove /system/bin/hijack and
   /system/bin/logwrapper
5. Copy /system/bin/logwrapper.bin to
   /system/bin/logwrapper
6. Run Voodo OTA Rootkeeper and save off root
7. In /System/bin/mount_ext3.sh, remove the last 3 lines, but keep the end
   newline (this will likely only be if you use Bionic Bootstrap
8. Reboot phone
9. Now you should be all set to download and install the OTA

I like to save off the OTA download, that way if I have problems installing it, it doesnt erase it from /cache and I have to redownload.  If you save off the download before unrooting (its in /cache directory) to say /mnt/sdcard-ext/dcim/, you can boot the phone into Recovery Mode by holding down both the volume up and volume down buttons and pressing the power button.  Once it starts to boot, let go of the power button, but continue to hold the two buttons.  Select Recovery.  Wait for the Android screen to pop up.  On mine, for some reason it didnt bring up the menu, so I pressed the volume up and volume down at the same time again and it displayed the options.  Select Install from external source and select the update.  Once it starts to update, you can press the volume up and down together again to enter verbose mode.  This will tell you exactly where its having issues.  This last paragraph is only needed if it fails.

Comment: My phone isn't rooted, but +1 for having the info here.